# A Clojure Spec that matches and generates an ordered vector of variable length

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Lets start out with the regular sequence of

```clj
(require '[clojure.spec     :as spec]
         '[clojure.spec.gen :as gen])
(spec/def ::cat (spec/cat :sym symbol? :str string? :kws (spec/* keyword?)))
```

which matches the vectors

```clj
(spec/conform ::cat '[af "5"])
=> {:sym af, :str "5"}
(spec/conform ::cat '[af "5" :key])
=> {:sym af, :str "5", :kws [:key]}
```

but also the lists

```clj
(spec/conform ::cat '(af "5"))
=> {:sym af, :str "5"}
(spec/conform ::cat '(af "5" :key))
=> {:sym af, :str "5", :kws [:key]}
```

If we want to constrain this we could try using `spec/tuple`; but sadly it only matches fixed length vectors, i.e it requires at at the least an empty list to be the last part of the tuple:

```clj
(spec/def ::tuple (spec/tuple symbol? string? (spec/* keyword?)))
(spec/conform ::tuple '[af "5"])
=> :clojure.spec/invalid
(spec/exercise ::tuple)
=> ([[r "" ()] [r "" []]] [[kE "" (:M)] [kE "" [:M]]] ...)
```

We can also try adding on an additional condition to `::cat` with `spec/and`:

```clj
(spec/def ::and-cat
  (spec/and vector? (spec/cat :sym symbol? :str string? :kws (spec/* keyword?))))
```

which matches fine

```clj
(spec/conform ::and-cat '[af "5"])
=> {:sym af, :str "5"}
(spec/conform ::and-cat '[af "5" :key])
=> {:sym af, :str "5", :kws [:key]}
(spec/conform ::and-cat '(af "5" :key))
=> :clojure.spec/invalid
```

but sadly fails in generating it's own data since the generator for `spec/cat` only produces lists which of course won't conform to the `vector?` predicate:

```clj
(spec/exercise ::and-cat)
=> Couldn't satisfy such-that predicate after 100 tries.
```

So to summarize: How does one write a spec which is both capable of accepting and generating vectors like `[hi "there"]` `[my "dear" :friend]`?

One could also rephrase the question as "Is there an alternative to `spec/cat` which generates vectors instead of lists?" or "Is it possible to pass a :kind argument to `spec/cat`?" or "Can I attach a generator to a spec which takes the output of the original generator and casts it to a vector?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the regex pattern independently from the spec:

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as s] '[clojure.spec.gen :as gen])

(def pattern 
  (s/cat :sym symbol? :str string? :kws (s/* keyword?)))

(s/def ::solution
  (s/with-gen (s/and vector? pattern) 
              #(gen/fmap vec (spec/gen pattern))))

(s/valid? ::solution '(af "5" :key))  ;; false

(s/valid? ::solution ['af "5" :key])  ;; true

(gen/sample (s/gen ::solution) 4)
;; ([m ""] [. "" :Q] [- "" :?-/-9y :_7*/!] [O._7l/.?*+ "z" :**Q.tw.!_/+!gN :wGR/K :n/L])
```

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. We are losing 'flatness' 

```

(s/def ::pattern (s/cat :sym symbol? :str string? :kws (s/* keyword?)))
(s/def ::pattern-2 (s/cat :s string? :p ::pattern))

(s/valid? ::pattern ['af "5" :key])  ;; true

(s/valid? ::pattern-2 ["string" 'af "5" :key])  ;; true

(s/def ::pattern-3 (s/cat :s string? :p ::solution))

(s/valid? ::pattern-3 ["string" 'af "5" :key])    ;; false !!!  <-  we are losing flattness
(s/valid? ::pattern-3 ["string" ['af "5" :key]])  ;; true  !!!  <-  we are losing flattness
```

Comment: Yes, that is one problem with the approach above - using the s/and will change ::solution from a regex op to a spec and only regex ops can be combined in a "flat" way. There is not one easy solution currently that satisfies all of the needs of a vector-only cat.

Comment: @AlexMiller How can I make coercion into a vector to be recursive, in the generator? For example to generate nested Hiccup structures.

Answer (score 0):

Turs out there is no trivial way of solving this as of `clojure-1.9.0-alpha15`. One possible solution is to modify the generator to cast the sequence given by cat into a vector like:

```
(spec/def ::solution
  (let [s (spec/cat :sym symbol? :str string? :kws (spec/* keyword?))]
    (spec/with-gen s #(gen/fmap vec (spec/gen s)))))
```

which we can then see both produces and accepts the correct data:

```
(spec/exercise ::solution)
=> ([[T ""] {:sym T, :str ""}]
    [[t* "Z" :g*] {:sym t*, :str "Z", :kws [:g*]}]
    [[G?8 "td" :*K/j] {:sym G?8, :str "td", :kws [:*K/j]}])
```

Though it has one problem, the spec doesn't verify that the input is a vector, it accepts sequences such as lists:

```
(spec/conform ::solution '(N-G.?8?4/- "" :G7y_.?Gx_/Oy1Dv :g!/Ooh0 :N-??h/o+cN))
=> {:sym N-G.?8?4/-, :str "", :kws [:G7y_.?Gx_/Oy1Dv :g!/Ooh0 :N-??h/o+cN]}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on Alex's solution, here's a macro which defines a vector-cat regex operation:

```
(defmacro vcat
  "Takes key+pred pairs, e.g.

  (vcat :e even? :o odd?)

  Returns a regex op that matches vectors, returning a map containing
  the keys of each pred and the corresponding value. The attached
  generator produces vectors."
  [& key-pred-forms]
  `(spec/with-gen (spec/and vector? (spec/cat ~@key-pred-forms))
     #(gen/fmap vec (spec/gen (spec/cat ~@key-pred-forms)))))
```